# Blacberry development: what do I need?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

1-I'm reading about developing Blackberry applications development on Blacberry developpers web site, but the reading make me more confuse.

Please, I would like to know the difference between:

```
BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse [v1.5],
BlackBerry Java SDK [v7.1], and
BlackBerry JDE [v5] Component Pack.
```

2-I've installed the following; what do I need now to develop a Hello World Blacberry application with eclipse 3.7?

```
BlackBerry Java Plug-in 1.5.0.201110141512  net.rim.EclipseJDE.feature.group    Research In Motion Ltd.
BlackBerry Java SDK 7.1.0.4 net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack7.1.0.feature.group   Research In Motion
BlackBerry Java SDK 7.0.0.33    net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack7.0.0.feature.group   Research In Motion
BlackBerry Java SDK 6.0.0.40    net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack6.0.0.feature.group   Research In Motion
BlackBerry Java SDK 5.0.0.25    net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack5.0.0.feature.group   Research In Motion
BlackBerry Java SDK 4.7.0.57    net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack4.7.0.feature.group   Research In Motion
BlackBerry Java SDK 4.6.1.49    net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack4.6.1.feature.group   Research In Motion
BlackBerry Java SDK 4.6.0.23    net.rim.ejde.feature.componentpack4.6.0.feature.group   Research In Motion

Mobile Tools for Java   1.1.2.201101310801  org.eclipse.mtj.feature.group   Eclipse.org - DSDP
Mobile Tools for Java Examples  1.1.2.201101310801  org.eclipse.mtj.examples.feature.group  Eclipse.org - DSDP
Mobile Tools for Java SDK   1.1.2.201101310801  org.eclipse.mtj.sdk.feature.group   Eclipse.org - DSDP
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything you need, and some stuff you don't.

Here's what each bit does:

- **BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse** - Adds the BlackBerry Development
  perspective, BlackBerry menu and various other useful features into
  Eclipse. In practice it means you can test, package, sign and deploy your
  BlackBerry app without delving into the command line.
- **BlackBerry Java SDK** - The tools (Software Development Kit) you need
  to build for a particular version of the BlackBerry OS. For example,
  the v5 of the SDK enables you to build applications which run on
  BlackBerry OS5 and above. Most importantly it includes the JRE (Java
  Runtime Environment) which you will build your app against.
- **Blackberry Java JDE** - The BlackBerry JDE (Java Development
  Environment) is a legacy, stand-alone development environment that
  contains similar tools. You don't need this if you're using the
  Eclipse plug-in.

To build a Hello World application in Eclipse go to File->New->BlackBerry Project, follow the wizard and choose Hello BlackBerry as the project template. Once created choose Run (Ctrl+F11), the simulator should load with your app installed on the home screen (or in the Downloads folder on OS5 and below).